# How to findout last commit from a git repository by commit message and cut text?

Tags: git, commit

For example I have the commits messages like:

```
Author: System update 0.1.12
...
System update 0.1.09
...
Author: System update 0.0.99
...
System update 0.0.43
...
Author: System update 0.0.1
```

How to findout last commit by commit message and cut text - version? In my case I need to findout:

```
Author: System update 0.1.12
```

and the get the version:

```
0.1.12
```

I can use

```
git log --grep="System update" --pretty=oneline | grep -m1 "System update"
```

but I got the string. And I am not sure about:

```
grep -m1 "System update"
```

Comment: you can use git log's results as an input to a script in the language you choose to develop. Would that work for you?

Comment: Yep. I need get last version and add commit message with a new one. For example I have last version '0.1.12', so I need write some func at .bash_profile for commit new updates. Like a gcsu (alias) and this fucntion get last commit with message like '\*System update\*' and get the version '0.1.12' and plus 1 and put the new commit message like 'Author: System update 0.1.13'. Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works as expected, couldn't you just limit the number of commits displayed by `git log`.

```
git log --grep="System update" -n 1 --pretty=oneline
```

Which only returns the last commit for me.

See [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)